# Cypress Code coverage within docker: failed to Fetch error

Tags: docker, code-coverage, cypress, e2e

I use Cypress v7.5.0 with https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage installed. There is nothing special about the config and setup, it is just like in the description.

I have a Vue3 test app running locally, inside a docker container. When I run Cypress on the host, everything works fine - coverage, tests, no problems.
However, if I run Cypress from within another docker container, then the tests fail due to code coverage, see screenshot:

[image: Error after running the tests]

I know that the error comes from the code coverage not just because of the sceenshot, but also because the tests run fine when I omit the coverage by runnig the tests with `cypress run --env coverage=false`.

Here is my docker-compose setup:

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:
  phoenix:
      build:
          context: .
      container_name: phoenix
      ports:
          - "4000:4000"
          - "4001:4001"
      networks:
          - mapp
      volumes:
          - ../:/app
      command: bash -c "
          cd /app && make run_phoenix_inside_docker
          "
  cypress:
      container_name: cypress
      # the Docker image to use from https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images
      image: "cypress/included:7.5.0"
      depends_on:
          - phoenix
      entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "./cypress_entrypoint.sh"]
      environment:
          # pass base url to test pointing at the web application
          - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://phoenix:4000
      # share the current folder as volume to avoid copying
      working_dir: /
      volumes:
          - ../E2E:/e2e
          - ./cypress_entrypoint.sh:/cypress_entrypoint.sh
      networks:
          - mapp
networks:
    mapp:
```

phoenix being the vue3 app, it works well from host when I add phoenix to my `/etc/hosts` but not when I run from within Cypress container.
Does anybody know what that `Failed to fetch` error means? The files are written by the way, so there is write access to the coverage folder.

The cypress entrypoint is just

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Init cypress..."
tail -F /dev/null
```

to avoid runnning the tests right after staring the container. I bash into the container and run `cd e2e && cypress run` from there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be coming from the `cy.request()` that fetches backend coverage, [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage/blob/c51751f9f9875c88aaacf648c738bec63b4163f1/support.js#L181)

**code-coverage/support.js**

```js
if (runningEndToEndTests && isIntegrationSpec) {
  // we can only request server-side code coverage
  // if we are running end-to-end tests,
  // otherwise where do we send the request?
  const url = Cypress._.get(
    Cypress.env('codeCoverage'),
    'url',
    '/__coverage__'
  )
  cy.request({
    url,
    log: false,
    failOnStatusCode: false
  })
```

You want to check that the url specified in cypress.json is available in Docker

**cypress.json**

```js
{
  "fixturesFolder": false,
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3003",
  "env": {
    "codeCoverage": {
      "url": "http://localhost:3003/__coverage__",
      "expectBackendCoverageOnly": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since I don't have backend coverage, what should that endpoint return?

Comment: Also it works when called from host, and there I don't have that endpoint either

Comment: @Stiegi, if you don't have a backend or have one but don't want it's coverage then make sure you don't have the above configuration.

Comment: @SteveZodiac Yes actually all tests failed if I activate this, which makes sense because the data the runner expects is not there. It is knd of strange however - if I comment out one of the tests in the spec file, it sometimes (!) works. I can see in my backend that the logic works, I receive all the requests I expect, all my assertions are true, however for some reason this fetch afterwards lets it sometimes fail (or always when running the complete test). Whatever, I stick with my non-fix solution for now

Answer (score 0):

I found a 'fix' that doesn't really fix the issue, but at least the tests don't fail anymore. In support/index.js, I just add

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  // returning false here prevents Cypress from
  // failing the test
  return false
})
```

Now the test runs within docker too.

Comment: This is fair enough if you are unable to id the cause. Uncaught exceptions usually originate in the app not the tests or plugins, but given that it occurs in the `after()` hook it's most likely caused by failed backend or unit test coverage.